# Dropdown javascript / jquery form validation debugging help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have the following jsfiddle setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/xCCA2/

Basically when a the form is submitted, the size select dropdown is validated to make sure a selection has been made. If a valid size has been selected then the form is posted.

If an invalid selection is made, then an alert box "An invalid size has been selected" should popup.

Please can I get help debugging this.

Nb: there will be many forms on a page, and  would prefer to uses classes rather than id's also there is some commented out html, where the form has been set a class, this works but anything within the form becomes clickable, which I do not want. Only the button should trigger the validation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".wq").live( "click", function () {
    alert("test");
   if($("select").val()!="")
       alert("not empty");
    else{
        alert("select a val");
    return false;
}
       // $(this).submit();    
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xCCA2/4/

Answer (score 0):

Look here

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Add

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

and required to the select

```
<select required
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4M6Wr/)